# Two Components, one with a set width

Tags: java, swing

This seems like a completely rudimentary question but I'm a beginner with swing. I have a resizable JFrame with a JPanel to the left and and a JTabbedPane to the right. I want the JTabbedPane to have a constant width and grow in height to match the JFrame height. The JPanel should fill the remaining width and height of the JFrame. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public Example()
{       
    f = new JFrame();

    f.setResizable(true);

    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));

    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JPanel viewerPanel = new JPanel()
    {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            System.out.println("W:" + getSize().width + ", H:" + getSize().height);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        }
    };  

    f.getContentPane().add(viewerPanel);

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    tabs.setSize(400, f.getHeight());

    tabs.addTab("Tab1", new JLabel("Content1"));
    tabs.addTab("Tab2", new JLabel("Content2"));
    tabs.addTab("Tab3", new JLabel("Content3"));
    tabs.addTab("Tab4", new JLabel("Content4"));

    f.getContentPane().add(tabs);

    f.pack();

    f.setVisible(true);     
}
```

Comment: Well, the basic answer to such questions is: you have to research the various **layout managers** that Java Swing offers to you. Start here for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: There is no need for the custom painting. All you need to do is use the `setBackground(...)` method of the panel to change its background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to let the layout do the work and setting preferred or minimum sizes :

Try using a BorderLayout and adding the panel to the center (which grows both in height and width) and adding your tabbedPane to the RIGHT (which grows in height) while setting a preferred or minimum size to your tabbedPane

Your tabbedPane should always have the same with, while the panel will grow according to the size there is left for him

Comment: *"to the RIGHT"* That is not a valid constant for `BorderLayout`. You must mean `LINE_END` or the older (& should be deprecated) `EAST`.

Comment: yes it is not a valid constant I shouldn't have used capslock

Comment: I disaggree though, EAST shouldn't be deprecated as it differs from LINE_END : if you switch your left to right orientation, LINE_END changes while EAST remains the same

Comment: That's exactly *why* the `EAST`/`WEST` constraints should be deprecated. For example, a `JTree` screws up when it is on the `WEST` but it is displaying Arabic.

Comment: I have migrated an app in arabic. You definitely need both constants according to the context as there are some things you don't want impacted by leftToRight